# Openshift proxy timeout

Tags: proxy, timeout, 502

I have an application hosted with Openshift and I need it to generate some Excel reports. The report generation process can take a long time (over 5 minutes). This causes the the client to see a 502 error and the request times out. How can and where can I configure my Openshift stack (it is a Java webapp running from Tomcat6) to increase the timeout duration?